# How can I convert a string of bytes to a byte object

Tags: python-3.x

So in python, you can write data to a file in bytes like this

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(data)
```

I have an api which does a cat on this file, and gives back the data looking like the example at the bottom

**here is the code that im having trouble with**

```
r = requests.get("http://ip/read/octo/exampleapikey123456789")
a = r.text
a = b''.join(a)

AMS.readMsg('private_octo.pem',a)
```

I get this error

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected a bytes-like object, str found
```

My question is, how do i convert the following string, into a 'bytes-like object)

Thanks :)

```
"b't\\xf8O\\xfc\\xa5\\xa1,\\x93\\xfeJ\\xd5>\\xf9\\x00\\xa9\\xd1\\xe1`\\x15\\xfe\\x88\\x0c\\xbf\\xc8!\\xfe\\xcd\\x007\\x14\\x05\\xd6\\xa5\\xbb\\nus\\x18\\x02\\x90\\xb9\\xd3\\x89\\x03\\xe3_@\\xf8\\xe1\\xa3\\x87\\x0c\\xe4)\\xb4\\xfd\\xe7\\xb2\\xdb\\x02~\\xeb\\x1a\\xba\\xa5\\xfc\\x90\\x88v\\xbe\\r\\x12bE\\x94\\xfe\\xdcI\"T\\x14\\x99%\\x862\\x9b}H\\xb74/\\x8f\\xaf\\xeae\\xe3\\xdb\\xd4\\x0cAc\\xc3\\xd3H\\xd6\\x00o\\xa8\\xf23DbM\\xfd\\x80+,Q\\xb5\\xc6\\xae\\r\\x06{+\\x1b$\\xb4\\xb8\\x8a\\xe0\\xec\\xfb\\xc0^}\\x85=\\xba\\xa6\\xa3L\\x17\\xbd;\\xe2\\xe0$\\xb0:\\x9bi\\x06\\x14\\xe5\\x8a-\\x95+\\nRK\\x97\\xdcz\\xbe\\x18\\x86Z\\xa6%k\\xfb\\x958X\\xa1P\\xf7\\x01\\x06\\xcd\\x02.\\x9bTt\\x8dzkU\\xe5V\\xb8>\\'7\\xf4\\x14%\\xc3W#\\x96\\x8b.\\x1cx\\'\\xae\\xa1\\xb8i&\\x11\\'\\xb5)\\xc2\\x8f\\x84\\x16N\\x8a\\xb5\\nC0!A\\x96y\\xfc\\xa3\\xf0\\x935\\xb2x9U\\x9a\\xe9\\xf9\\xee\\xfa\\xce\\x13\\x9a1\\xd5\\x99\\xf2\\xfd\\xbf\\x80'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> obj = ast.literal_eval("b't\\xf8O\\xfc\\xa5\\xa1,\\x93\\xfeJ\\xd5>\\xf9\\x00\\xa9\\xd1\\xe1`\\x15\\xfe\\x88\\x0c\\xbf\\xc8!\\xfe\\xcd\\x007\\x14\\x05\\xd6\\xa5\\xbb\\nus\\x18\\x02\\x90\\xb9\\xd3\\x89\\x03\\xe3_@\\xf8\\xe1\\xa3\\x87\\x0c\\xe4)\\xb4\\xfd\\xe7\\xb2\\xdb\\x02~\\xeb\\x1a\\xba\\xa5\\xfc\\x90\\x88v\\xbe\\r\\x12bE\\x94\\xfe\\xdcI\"T\\x14\\x99%\\x862\\x9b}H\\xb74/\\x8f\\xaf\\xeae\\xe3\\xdb\\xd4\\x0cAc\\xc3\\xd3H\\xd6\\x00o\\xa8\\xf23DbM\\xfd\\x80+,Q\\xb5\\xc6\\xae\\r\\x06{+\\x1b$\\xb4\\xb8\\x8a\\xe0\\xec\\xfb\\xc0^}\\x85=\\xba\\xa6\\xa3L\\x17\\xbd;\\xe2\\xe0$\\xb0:\\x9bi\\x06\\x14\\xe5\\x8a-\\x95+\\nRK\\x97\\xdcz\\xbe\\x18\\x86Z\\xa6%k\\xfb\\x958X\\xa1P\\xf7\\x01\\x06\\xcd\\x02.\\x9bTt\\x8dzkU\\xe5V\\xb8>\\'7\\xf4\\x14%\\xc3W#\\x96\\x8b.\\x1cx\\'\\xae\\xa1\\xb8i&\\x11\\'\\xb5)\\xc2\\x8f\\x84\\x16N\\x8a\\xb5\\nC0!A\\x96y\\xfc\\xa3\\xf0\\x935\\xb2x9U\\x9a\\xe9\\xf9\\xee\\xfa\\xce\\x13\\x9a1\\xd5\\x99\\xf2\\xfd\\xbf\\x80'")
>>> obj
b't\xf8O\xfc\xa5\xa1,\x93\xfeJ\xd5>\xf9\x00\xa9\xd1\xe1`\x15\xfe\x88\x0c\xbf\xc8!\xfe\xcd\x007\x14\x05\xd6\xa5\xbb\nus\x18\x02\x90\xb9\xd3\x89\x03\xe3_@\xf8\xe1\xa3\x87\x0c\xe4)\xb4\xfd\xe7\xb2\xdb\x02~\xeb\x1a\xba\xa5\xfc\x90\x88v\xbe\r\x12bE\x94\xfe\xdcI"T\x14\x99%\x862\x9b}H\xb74/\x8f\xaf\xeae\xe3\xdb\xd4\x0cAc\xc3\xd3H\xd6\x00o\xa8\xf23DbM\xfd\x80+,Q\xb5\xc6\xae\r\x06{+\x1b$\xb4\xb8\x8a\xe0\xec\xfb\xc0^}\x85=\xba\xa6\xa3L\x17\xbd;\xe2\xe0$\xb0:\x9bi\x06\x14\xe5\x8a-\x95+\nRK\x97\xdcz\xbe\x18\x86Z\xa6%k\xfb\x958X\xa1P\xf7\x01\x06\xcd\x02.\x9bTt\x8dzkU\xe5V\xb8>\'7\xf4\x14%\xc3W#\x96\x8b.\x1cx\'\xae\xa1\xb8i&\x11\'\xb5)\xc2\x8f\x84\x16N\x8a\xb5\nC0!A\x96y\xfc\xa3\xf0\x935\xb2x9U\x9a\xe9\xf9\xee\xfa\xce\x13\x9a1\xd5\x99\xf2\xfd\xbf\x80'
>>> obj[0]
116
>>> obj[1]
248
```

Comment: It kind of worked: the a object iss realy this, and ast turns it into a string not bytes. `'"b\'t\\\\xf8O\\\\xfc\\\\xa5\\\\xa1,........ too long......\\\\n'

Comment: @AngusClayto, can you update your question with the string you are trying to transform then?